# BJQS Slider pause on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, toggle, bjqs

I am using a BJQS slider on my website.

I am also using fancybox on the same website.

I would like BJQS to pause when the fancybox is open and resume when closed.

Does anyone know how I could create a pause/play toggle button for BJQS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fancybox comes with some callbacks, so you should be able to do something like:

Adopting Lee and Edwards idea about virtual hovering..

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    padding : 0,
    openEffect : 'elastic',
    closeEffect: 'elastic',
    beforeLoad: function(){
        $(".banner").trigger("mouseover");
    },
    afterClose: function(){
        $(".banner").trigger("mouseout");
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!! Thank you Danny, I think you may have just saved me from going insane. You truly are a wonderful man and a Stack Overlord!!

Comment: Just a point, I think other answers must be upvoted too as a part of the solution.

Comment: Edward, I did actually upvote Lee when he posted his answer originally, it's only when i tried to replicate it that I thought this was a more elegant way, But i have upvoted yours as well now..

Answer (score 1):

Without editing the source file to provide either a method to pause the slider, or add in a button you can hide and trigger a click on, the quickest method is to trigger the mouse events that cause the slider to pause.

Looking at the demo, you can see that when you `mouseover` the slider, the slider stops animating until you move your mouse outside of it. Therefore you can simulate these events.

Assuming your slider div is `#slider` like the demo on the BJQS site, you would do:

**On fancybox open**

```
$('#slider').trigger('mouseover');
```

**On fancybox close**

```
$('#slider').trigger('mouseout');
```

Go here: http://fancybox.net/api to see how to define open/close callbacks (see near bottom of first table, the "on" options)

Answer (score 1):

I check the plugin but I cant' find any method to pause/play the slider.

I see an option called:

> hoverpause      : true,     // enable/disable pause slides on hover

So we can "hack" in this way using it by triggering the over state on the slider itself:

```
var stopbjqs = false;
$(function () {
    $('#dialog').bjqs({
        'showmarkers': false,
            'responsive': true,
            'automatic': true
    });

    $("#btn").click(function () {
        if (!stopbjqs) {
            $("#dialog").trigger("mouseover");
            stopbjqs=true;
        } else {
            $("#dialog").trigger("mouseout");
            stopbjqs=false;
        }
    });

});
```

But it will be definitely better to have some methods to manipulate the slider.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/P8UgQ/

Answer (score 0):

Came across this whilst trying add a play/pause button to the plugin. @Irvin Dominin's suggestion relating to `hoverpause` is good but it will fail as soon as you hover the banners as the mouseover/mouseout is triggered.

I decided to extend the plugin with a new setting and turn off `hoverpause`.

First add the setting to the `defaults` object e.g.

```
// slider default settings
var defaults = {
    enableplaypause: false  // shows play/pause button
};
```

Next you'll want to set the click binding to your button, this is done in the `init()` function e.g.

```
// run through options and initialise settings
var init = function () {

    // configurations only avaliable if more than 1 slide
    if (state.slidecount > 1) {

        //enable play/pause button using setting we defined earlier
        if (settings.enableplaypause) {
            conf_enableplaypause();
        }
    }
};
```

Now for the `conf_enableplaypause();` function which handles the state + button bindings:

```
var conf_enableplaypause = function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        if (!state.paused) {
            clearInterval(state.interval);
            state.paused = true;
            $('#btn').text('PAUSED');
        } else {
            state.interval = setInterval(function () {
                go(vars.fwd, false);
            }, settings.animspeed);
            state.paused = false;
            $('#btn').text('PLAYING');
        }
    });
};
```

Pretty straightforward and is essentially a copy of what `hoverpause` does except on a button click along with updating the button text.

Hopefully this helps someone